# App-store submission

Tags: ios, ios6, ios7, app-store

According to latest Apple's new [submission rules](http://techcrunch.com/2013/12/17/apple-requiring-all-app-submissions-to-be-optimized-for-ios-7-by-feb-1st/) apps which would have built with ios 6 sdk will be rejected after february 1st

But I can't make one thing clear : will Apple submit apps built with lates sdk 7.0 and deployment target set up to 6.0 after february 1st?

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about App Store compliance, not a coding issue. Please see [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic for Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/175701)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about app store submission

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://developer.apple.com/news/index.php?id=12172013a#top

Your app should be optimized for iOS7 means you have to compile it with iOS 7 SDK as Base SDK. Yes they will accept app with Deployment Target 6.0 and even lower.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The SDK you're using and your deployment target are two different things.

Answer (score 2):

Apple will review app that has base SDK iOS7.0, base SDK basically defines that you can use all the public API up to your base SDK.
while deployment target is minimum version you want to support, so you can set it what ever you want but base SDK should be iOS7.