# Temporarily remove app from store while update is waiting for review?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

The current version of my app for sale in the App Store is broken in iOS8. I have an update to correct those issues "waiting for review" but I don't want new users using iOS8 purchasing my app in the meantime while the update is in process, which it seems like it might be for quite some time. How can I pull it from the store without removing my update as well? I tried changing the availability date but I keep getting error `You must select a valid available date.` I'm not even sure if that's the way to do it anyway.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about App Store policies and not computer programming. (You should contact the App Store to see if they can expedite your App Review, or temporarily remove the old app.)

Comment: @AaronBrager Questions like this are on topic. This site also allows for questions related to common tools used by developers. Using iTunes Connect is a common tool used by iOS developers.

Comment: @rmaddy [This Meta page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175723) disagrees with you, and there are many other similar closed questions ([example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20718848/app-store-submission))

Comment: @AaronBrager In my opinion, neither of your links apply to this question. This question is a developer question about a developer tool. It has a concrete answer with a fixed set of steps. It's not dependent on Apple or their whims or policies.

Comment: @rmaddy I see your point, but the question you duped this to refers to permanently removing an app from the store. This question refers to temporarily removing an app pending an update. Following the steps in the question you linked to will change the app's status to “Developer Removed From Sale” and remove it from the review queue. I think the question you linked to is valid, but this question is essentially a customer service question, without a concrete answer.

Comment: @AaronBrager Unless I'm mistaken, the OP can follow the duplicate to temporarily remove the current version from the app store. When the update gets reviewed, they undo the change to put the app back into the store.